# Como fazer download das NF-e de um CNPJ em C#?

Tags: nfe, uninfe

Uso o *UniNFe* para comunicação com a Sefaz. Consegui realizar o evento de consulta dos documentos do destinatário e obtive o retorno das informações resumidas e dos NSU. 
Mas não consigo o layout da solicitação de download (arquivo com final -nfe-down.xml.

Como fazer download das NF-e de um CNPJ usando C#?

Answer (score 1):

A SEFAZ agora não tem mais o layout -nfe-down.xml, na hora que vc faz as consultas ela mesma já faz o download dos XMLs que já foram manifestados.

Segue link de um manual do uninfe que trata da manifestação e download de XML, analise:

http://wiki.unimake.com.br/index.php/Manuais:UniNFe/duv3

Qualquer dúvida, segue meu e-mail: wandrey@unimake.com.br

Comment: Uma honra ter o Wandrey respondendo aqui.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua disponibilidade e presteza.